# Implementing Monoidal in terms of Applicative

Tags: haskell

[Typeclassopedia](https://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Typeclassopedia#Alternative_formulation) presents the following exercise:

> Implement pure and (<*>) in terms of unit and (**), and vice versa.

Here's `Monoidal` and `MyApplicative`:

```
class Functor f => Monoidal f where
  u :: f ()                          -- using `u` rather than `unit` 
  dotdot :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)    -- using instead of `(**)`

class Functor f => MyApplicative f where
  p     :: a -> f a                  -- using instead of `pure`
  apply :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b  -- using instead of `(<**>)`
```

First, let me show the `Maybe`-like data type:

```
data Option a = Some a 
                | None deriving Show
```

Then, I defined `instance MyApplicative Option`:

```
instance MyApplicative Option where
  p                = Some
  apply None _     = None
  apply _ None     = None
  apply (Some g) f = fmap g f
```

Finally, my attempt at implementing `Monoidal Option` in terms of `p` and `apply` of `MyApplicative`:

```
instance Monoidal Option where
  u                        = p ()
  dotdot None _            = None 
  dotdot _ None            = None
  dotdot (Some x) (Some y) = Some id <*> Some (x, y)
```

Is this right? My implementation of `dotdot` with `apply` doesn't seem

```
instance Monoidal Option where
  u                        = p ()
  dotdot None _            = None 
  dotdot _ None            = None
  dotdot (Some x) (Some y) = apply (Some id) (Some (x, y))
```

In particular, I'm curious about how to properly implement `dotdot :: f a -> f b -> f (a, b)` with Applicative's `(<*>)` - in my case it's `apply`.

Comment: Most of this is explained quickly in the beginning of the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23320391/414413

Comment: that explanation is quite nice - thanks. Care to post here for credit?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Applicative` is a neat alternative presentation of `Monoidal`. Both typeclasses are equivalent, and you can convert between the two without considering a specific data type like `Option`. The "neat alternative presentation" for `Applicative` is based on the following two equivalencies

```
pure a = fmap (const a) unit
unit = pure ()

ff <*> fa = fmap (\(f,a) -> f a) $ ff ** fa
fa ** fb = pure (,) <*> fa <*> fb
```

The trick to get this "neat alternative presentation" for `Applicative` is the same as the trick for `zipWith` - replace explicit types and constructors in the interface with things that the type or constructor can be passed into to recover what the original interface was.

```
unit :: f ()
```

is replaced with `pure` which we can substitute the type `()` and the constructor `() :: ()` into to recover `unit`.

```
pure :: a  -> f a
pure    () :: f ()
```

And similarly (though not as straightforward) for substituting the type `(a,b)` and the constructor `(,) :: a -> b -> (a,b)` into `liftA2` to recover `**`.

```
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2    (,)           :: f a -> f b -> f (a,b)
```

`Applicative` then gets the nice `<*>` operator by lifting function application `($) :: (a -> b) -> a -> b` into the functor.

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) = liftA2 ($)
```

Getting from `<*>` back to `liftA2` is common enough that [`liftA2` is included in `Control.Applicative`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.7.0.1/docs/src/Control-Applicative.html#liftA2). The `<$>` is infix `fmap`.

```
liftA2 :: Applicative f => (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f a b = f <$> a <*> b
```