# What are the applicative functor laws in terms of pure and liftA2?

Tags: haskell, applicative

I'm playing around with formulating Applicative in terms of `pure` and `liftA2` (so that `(<*>) = liftA2 id` becomes a derived combinator).

I can think of a bunch of candidate laws, but I'm not sure what the minimal set would be.

1. `f <$> pure x = pure (f x)`
2. `f <$> liftA2 g x y = liftA2 ((f .) . g) x y`
3. `liftA2 f (pure x) y = f x <$> y`
4. `liftA2 f x (pure y) = liftA2 (flip f) (pure y) x`
5. `liftA2 f (g <$> x) (h <$> y) = liftA2 (\x y -> f (g x) (h y)) x y`
6. ...

Comment: `liftA2` is defined in terms of `<$>` and `<*>`, I don't know why you would want to instead define `<*>` in terms of `liftA2`.

Comment: Yeah, but I'd like to do something similar to what EZ Yang does in his post comparing Applicative and Monoidal: http://blog.ezyang.com/2012/08/applicative-functors/

Comment: `Applicative` with `pure` and `liftA2` is the same as this [`Monoidal`](http://www.haskellforall.com/2014/07/equational-reasoning-at-scale.html) class which has a list of laws. To get from `Monoidal` to `Applicative` with `pure` and `liftA2` you [replace explicit types and constructors in the interface with things that the type or constructor can be passed into to recover the original interface](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27262462/414413).

Comment: @Cirdec, neat. Is is easy to read off the corresponding laws for `pure` and `liftA2`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on McBride and Paterson's [laws for `Monoidal`](http://staff.city.ac.uk/~ross/papers/Applicative.pdf)(section 7) I'd suggest the following laws for `liftA2` and `pure`.

***left and right identity***

```
liftA2 (\_ y -> y) (pure x) fy       = fy
liftA2 (\x _ -> x) fx       (pure y) = fx
```

***associativity***

```
liftA2 id           (liftA2 (\x y z -> f x y z) fx fy) fz =
liftA2 (flip id) fx (liftA2 (\y z x -> f x y z)    fy  fz)
```

***naturality***

```
liftA2 (\x y -> o (f x) (g y)) fx fy = liftA2 o (fmap f fx) (fmap g fy)
```

It isn't immediately apparent that these are sufficient to cover the relationship between `fmap` and `Applicative`'s `pure` and `liftA2`. Let's see if we can prove from the above laws that

```
fmap f fx = liftA2 id (pure f) fx
```

We'll start by working on `fmap f fx`. All of the following are equivalent.

```
fmap f fx
liftA2 (\x _ -> x) (fmap f fx) (         pure y )     -- by right identity
liftA2 (\x _ -> x) (fmap f fx) (     id (pure y))     -- id x = x by definition
liftA2 (\x _ -> x) (fmap f fx) (fmap id (pure y))     -- fmap id = id (Functor law)
liftA2 (\x y -> (\x _ -> x) (f x) (id y)) fx (pure y) -- by naturality
liftA2 (\x _ -> f x                     ) fx (pure y) -- apply constant function
```

At this point we've written `fmap` in terms of `liftA2`, `pure` and any `y`; `fmap` is entirely determined by the above laws. The remainder of the as-yet-unproven proof is left by the irresolute author as an exercise for the determined reader.

Comment: Interesting, that the identity law can be rewritten like so: `liftA2 const fx (pure y) == const fx (pure y)` and `flip (liftA2 (flip const)) fx (pure y) == const fx (pure y)` (or `liftA2 (flip const) (pure x) fy == flip const (pure x) fy`), which perhaps adds an interesting angle.

Answer (score 3):

If you define `(<.>) = liftA2 (.)` then the laws become very nice:

```hs
pure id <.> f = f
f <.> pure id = f
f <.> (g <.> h) = (f <.> g) <.> h
```

Apparently `pure f <.> pure g = pure (f . g)` follows for free. I believe this formulation [originates with Daniel Mlot](https://duplode.github.io/posts/applicative-archery.html).

Answer (score -1):

Per the online book, [Learn You A Haskell:Functors, Applicative Functors and Monoids](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids#applicative-functors), the Appplicative Functor laws are bellow but reorganized for formatting reasons; however, I am making this post community editable since it would be useful if someone could embed derivations:

```
    identity]               v = pure id <*> v
homomorphism]      pure (f x) = pure f <*> pure x
 interchange]    u <*> pure y = pure ($ y) <*> u
 composition] u <*> (v <*> w) = pure (.) <*> u <*> v <*> w
```

Note:

```
function composition]  (.) = (b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)
application operator]    $ = (a->b) -> a -> b
```

[Found a treatment on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/2lompe/where_do_the_applicative_laws_come_from/)

Comment: Should `(.)` not be `(a->b) -> (b->c) -> (a->c)` ?

Comment: No, it should be `(b->c) -> (a->b) -> (a->c)`.

Comment: Indeed: (f . g) a = f (g(a))

Comment: "...  in terms of pure and liftA2", asks the question.